# SQL Server check resultant data type of expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, types

Normally I would put the data type into a temp table and inspect the table column type, e.g.

```
select 1.0 N into tbl

sp_help tbl
```

Column N then reveals the data type of the expression `1.0`.  (This is a only simple example)

There is a SQL function to inspect the data type of an expression directly, but the name escapes me right now.

What is the name of this function?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

[SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx) is close

```
DECLARE @what sql_variant;
DECLARE @foo decimal(19,3) = 1, @bar decimal(11,7) = 2;

SELECT @what = @foo / @bar;
SELECT
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'BaseType'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'Precision'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'Scale'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'MaxLength');

SELECT @what = @foo + @bar;
SELECT
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'BaseType'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'Precision'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'Scale'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'MaxLength');


SELECT @what = @foo * @bar;
SELECT
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'BaseType'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'Precision'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'Scale'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@what, 'MaxLength');
```

Or temp table/SELECT..INTO.. as an extension of what you've already done

Edit: [Remus' answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926097/ms-sql-server-indicating-varbinarymax-fields-datatype-in-vb-net)

Comment: It's worth noting that there are types that this doesn't work on, such as nvarchar(max).

Comment: Also maxlength for nvarchar results is doubled so nvarchar(7) shows 14 bytes which makes sense, but just something to be mindful of.

Answer (score 6):

All that I can think of are the [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) and [ISDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) functions.

These will return a 1/0 when passed an expression.  I can't think of anything that will return the type if given an expression unfortunately.

**UPDATE:**

Try [SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx)!  I think this is what you are looking for.  Hard to track down...

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen such a function.

From the MSDN article on [T-SQL expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286.aspx):

> For a simple expression made up of a
>   single constant, variable, scalar
>   function, or column name: the data
>   type, collation, precision, scale, and
>   value of the expression is the data
>   type, collation, precision, scale, and
>   value of the referenced element.
>
> When two expressions are combined by
>   using comparison or logical operators,
>   the resulting data type is Boolean and
>   the value is one of the following:
>   TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN. For more
>   information about Boolean data types,
>   see Comparison Operators
>   (Transact-SQL).
>
> When two expressions are combined by
>   using arithmetic, bitwise, or string
>   operators, the operator determines the
>   resulting data type.
>
> Complex expressions made up of many
>   symbols and operators evaluate to a
>   single-valued result. The data type,
>   collation, precision, and value of the
>   resulting expression is determined by
>   combining the component expressions,
>   two at a time, until a final result is
>   reached. The sequence in which the
>   expressions are combined is defined by
>   the precedence of the operators in the
>   expression.

Comment: Now you have - see gbn's answer

Comment: @cyberkiwi: Yes, his answer is close and I've upvoted it, but original post was asking for a function to evaluate an expression directly.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't one. You can see info about a type (TYPEPROPERTY). Or a column (sys.columns etc) but not a random expression unless a computed column. An expression by itself has no persistence unless it's a column: you also want to know determinism etc too which is only valid for a column

Comment: As phrased in the question, using `select sql_variant_property(1.0, 'basetype')` tells me SQL sees it as type numeric. That's a perfect fit.