# How to find the derived column types of a view in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

For example, suppose I have a view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[PaymentSchedule_vw]
AS
    SELECT
         [Order].Id                [Order Id]
        ,[PaymentSchedule].Date    [Payment Date]
    FROM
        _Order123 [Order]
        INNER JOIN
            _Order123_Shedule [PaymentSchedule]
            ON
            [Order].Id = [PaymentSchedule].OrderId

GO
```

How do I discover the types of `[Order Id]` and `[Payment Date]`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT c.name,
       t.name,
       c.max_length,
       c.precision,
       c.scale
FROM   sys.columns c
       JOIN sys.types t
         ON t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
            AND t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID('PaymentSchedule_vw')
```

Or you can use `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY` - [some examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008217/sql-server-check-resultant-data-type-of-expression/5008433#5008433).

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT top 1
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY([Order Id], 'BaseType') OrderIdBaseType,
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY([Payment Date], 'BaseType') PaymentDateBaseType
FROM [PaymentSchedule_vw]
```

You should check the following properties:

```
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(<column>, 'BaseType'), 
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(<column>, 'Precision'), 
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(<column>, 'Scale'), 
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(<column>, 'MaxLength')
```

Advanage with using SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY is that it can also be used on computed columns and expressions

Comment: Worth noting that SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY is from SQL Server 2008 and above.

Comment: @SubqueryCrunch I agree with you because the question is tagged with sql-server-2005 - I didn't realize this when I posted it. However since I write this comment in 2018 when 2005 is no longer supported - I hope this fact has very low impact