# How to print the data type of a constant

Tags: sql, sql-server

Python has a type function. Is there a SQL function or other method to print the data type of a constant such as 50 or 'Hello' ?  Just using this as a learning tool.

Comment: Are you talking about a constant object or a literal value?

Comment: I don't see a difference in this case, but I gave two examples, so whatever those are called.

Comment: Beware - this smells like a bad [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Suggest you back up and reconsider your "learning". TSQL is not like more modern languages. You might consider the [variant documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Typically if you want a literal to be evaluated as a specific type you cast it as such. Implicit conversion can be a bad habit.

Comment: See [sql-server-check-resultant-data-type-of-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008217/sql-server-check-resultant-data-type-of-expression)

Comment: @SMor Are you assuming that no one reads code written by others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to return data type meta data of a T-SQL constant is with `sp_describe_first_result_set`. Example usage with a SELECT query containing an integer constaint:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT 1';
```

Result:

```
+-----------+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------------+------------+-----------+-------+----------------+--------------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+-------------+------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| is_hidden | column_ordinal | name | is_nullable | system_type_id | system_type_name | max_length | precision | scale | collation_name | user_type_id | user_type_database | user_type_schema | user_type_name | assembly_qualified_type_name | xml_collection_id | xml_collection_database | xml_collection_schema | xml_collection_name | is_xml_document | is_case_sensitive | is_fixed_length_clr_type | source_server | source_database | source_schema | source_table | source_column | is_identity_column | is_part_of_unique_key | is_updateable | is_computed_column | is_sparse_column_set | ordinal_in_order_by_list | order_by_is_descending | order_by_list_length | tds_type_id | tds_length | tds_collation_id | tds_collation_sort_id |
+-----------+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------------+------------+-----------+-------+----------------+--------------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+-------------+------------+------------------+-----------------------+
|         0 |              1 | NULL |           0 |             56 | int              |          4 |        10 |     0 | NULL           | NULL         | NULL               | NULL             | NULL           | NULL                         | NULL              | NULL                    | NULL                  | NULL                |               0 |                 0 |                        0 | NULL          | NULL            | NULL          | NULL         | NULL          |                  0 | NULL                  |             0 |                  1 |                    0 | NULL                     | NULL                   | NULL                 |          56 |          4 | NULL             | NULL                  |
+-----------+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------------+------------+-----------+-------+----------------+--------------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+-------------+------------+------------------+-----------------------+
```

**EDIT:**

@Larnu mentioned in comments that the `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` TVF provides similar functionality. For your use case, that function facilitates getting only the type name column from the result:

```
DECLARE @ConstantExpression nvarchar(MAX) = '1';
SELECT system_type_name FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT '+@ConstantExpression,DEFAULT,DEFAULT);
```

Result:

```
system_type_name
int
```

Comment: There's also a similarly named and functionally function to the above procedure< [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Larnu. I added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY function and specify different property names, for example 'basetype' etc.  Something like this

```
declare @col            varchar(8000)='Hello';

select sql_variant_property(@col, 'basetype') sql_base_type,
       sql_variant_property(@col, 'precision') sql_precision,
       sql_variant_property(@col, 'scale') sql_scale,
       sql_variant_property(@col, 'MaxLength') sql_maxlen;
```

```
sql_base_type   sql_precision   sql_scale   sql_maxlen
varchar         0               0           8000
```